# Should maven compile time dependency be necessarily packaged for access during runtime?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

Should maven compile time dependency be necessarily packaged for access during runtime ?

Let's assume that there is a maven pom file for a library A.
On that, maven dependency tree command is run.

And in the output, we see the following line:

```
[INFO] +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.3:compile
```

This means that, commons-pool.jar should be available during compilation.
Does this imply that, necessarily, commons-pool.jar should be packaged alongside library A, inorder for access during runtime ?

Comment: Yes. But if you have any particular problem, please mention it straight. It's much easier to give/get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer is yes, as Alanpatchi said.

In Maven compile dependencies are also runtime dependencies.